# My comments on YouTube videos never appear?

Tags: youtube, comments

I noticed that since a few days, when I place a comment or feedback at some YouTube video, it doesn't appear.

Actually it does seem to appear on **my** session, when I'm logged in. But when I visit the same video with another browser, the comment isn't there.

I've already tried waiting a bit, maybe it needed some time to process (even though with the first browser it appears immediately). I also made sure to sort comments on Newest first, but I could see both older and new comments there, placed earlier and later than mine, but mine wasn't there.

Is there some weird kind of censorship going on, or what can cause this? Let me explicitly stress the fact that in no way did I possibly place any dubious, questionable, rule breaking, or otherwise undesirable comment or spam or bad language whatsoever.

Comment: can you share such a comment?

Comment: @user0 No, it seems I can't. For example with [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xr8lrBAfHcA), I placed [this comment](https://i.imgur.com/d6d7y5g.jpg) (screenshot) a few days ago. The comment is there when I'm logged in. But when visiting the same video from another browser, it isn't.

Comment: indeed its not there. I imagine you are by some (maybe) mistake blacklisted by youtube comment bot, therefore I suggest contacting youtube support via https://i.imgur.com/w1uITiZ.png?1

Answer (score 1):

YouTube once introduced a stupid spam filter, which forces channel owners to review *countless* of comments - and many of those are good ones! A video with less comments gets a worse ranking. YouTube even blocks ads for whole non-profit channels, if they dared to publish serious political content. This is how YouTube lets you discover "high-ranking" stupid "wow-look-at-me" videos on its startpage.

So these are just few reasons why YouTube is no longer a social *YOU*-tube. YouTube once deserved its name, before it was owned by Google.